# getting out of loop, after the input ends

Tags: arrays, c, char, scanf, user-input

So , i am given a list of inputs:

```
hello
123456
124
5223
food
7
```

what i must do is , look at the every single element of the list, and check if the cross sum is equal to 7 (for example: 124 = 1 + 2 + 4 = 7, meaning , the number is valid)
So the output , we get , must be:(in console it should looks like this:)

```
hello
hello is invalid
123456
123456 is invalid
124
124 is valid
5223
5223 is invalid
food
food is invalid
7
7 is valid
```

Here's the program i wrote :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN 99    
int cross_sum(int length ,char *name){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length ; i++){
        if(name[i] != 0){
            sum = sum +( name[i] -48);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
int check_crosssum( int number){
    if( number % 10 == 7)
    {
        return 0;
    }   
        return -1;
}
    

int main (void) {

   
    char name[MAXN] ;
    int sum = 0;
   
    while (scanf("%98[^\n]", name) == 1)  {         
            int len = strlen(name);
            sum = cross_sum(len,name);
            int pruf_summe = check_crosssum(sum);
            if( pruf_summe == 0 && len <= 20  ){
                printf("%s is valid \n" , name);
            }
            else{
                printf("%s is invalid \n" , name);
            }
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

when i run the program, all it does it looks at the first element then ends it.
So the output, which i am  getting is:

```
hello
hello is invalid
----------
(program exited with code: 0)
```

How can i process each inputs individually with help of while loop?
Or is there any other way, where programms runs till no input is given!
i also tried with

```
while(1)
```

it did't seem to work.
Any idea , or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1):

If you clear the input string before reading it, and make your exit condition be an "empty string", you should be fine:

```
int sum = 0;

do {
    name[0] = '\0';
    scanf("%s", name);
    ...

} while (strlen(name) > 1);
```

Comment: but then it will end at the first number, whose cross sum is seven,and ignore the rest... it must run till end of inputs @mmixLinus

Comment: @Sjo9  Ok, misunderstood your ending criterion.  Edited my answer.

Comment: i tried it but, it didn't terminated the program, when i pressed enter

Comment: @Sjo9 Yes, you probably have the newline character in `name`. Fixed that end condition too.

Comment: it really didn't worked for me, scanf tries to avoid reading blank space and waits till user gives any inputs and , if i use EOF , it just goes on a infinite loop with the last number i entered

Comment: @Sjo9 If you clear `name` before scanf it should handle EOF too. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can change condition from this

```cs
while (scanf("%98[^\n]", name) == 1)
```

to this

```cs
while (scanf(" %98[^\n]", name) == 1)  {
```

It will work for every input.
Adding space will ignore newline character.